# How could I do to mmap a large memory area with Anonymous Mappings but no-zero-filled to be done?

Tags: linux, system-calls, mmap

As *The Linux Programming Interface * said Anonymous Mappings: With both the MAP_ANONYMOUS and the /dev/zero techniques, the bytes of the resulting mapping are initialized to 0.

I want to mmap a memory area with very big size(1 GB). The source area is filled with my own data. But these data would be zero-filled in dest mmaped area if I use Anonymous mmap which will not use any File Descriptor.

HOW could I do to mmap a big size memory area with my own data still valid in dest area after mmap operation?

Or is there another way to achieve this goals?

Comment: `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` exists, but it requires the kernel to allow it (because mapped pages might have someone else's data) and still wouldn't get you the data from your source buffer. Pages are also generally zeroed on demand, not up-front (unless you're using `MAP_POPULATE`). Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @LeBron GanDalf – I don't understand your goals. `mmap()` creates a new mapping, not a mapping of your source area, unless there is a device driver doing that. What kind of memory area is your _own data_ in: virtual, or physical?

Comment: @Armali  Thanks for your reply! My own data is filled with many map structures which contain the map relationship between two elements. Even though all my own data doesn't take up 1GB size capacity, I still want to use mmap to create a mapping area which is 1GB size big to accommodate all these map structures . These map structures may grow up but I can ensure that they will not exceed 1GB. THE MOST IMPORTANT IS that I wonder all my own data could be oprated within the 1GB size area which is allocated by mmap.

Comment: @Hasturkun   I want to handle many structures within an area which is created by mmap mapping mechanism. The size of these structures maybe be a little big but will not excceed 1GB.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. It just sounds like your data is already present in your virtual memory space. If you want to `mmap` something to a virtual address which is in use already, that's not doable. - If you want the structures to be within a `mmap` area, you have to create the area first, then write the structures into it.

Comment: @Armali  If you want the structures to be within a mmap area, you have to create the area first, then write the structures into it--------------What is the best choice to create a 1GB size area even though not all this 1-GB-size-area would be filled with data? only use mmap(void * ptr, 1ul*1024*1024*1024,................ )?

Comment: I see no significantly different choices; maybe using MAP_HUGETLB besides MAP_ANONYMOUS is worth considering.

Comment: @Armali     Thanks very much!! I will go to learn MAP_HUGETLB flag right now.

Comment: Don't bother too much - it's uncertain whether MAP_HUGETLB will make a noticable difference.